# 1 Equation Guess-Check Efficiency

Tags: linear-algebra

Write the statement for the problem in mathematical language. Use x for the tens digit and y for the unit digits in the two digit numbers.

Find the two-digit number which is greater than the product of its digits by 26.

Statement: $10x+y=x\cdot y+26$

How would I go about solving this efficiently?

Comment: Well, obviously $x\geq 2,$ so I would substitute the values $2,3,4,\dots,9$ for $x$ and see if $y$ turns out to be an integer between $0$ and $9$.

Comment: Why is it greater than 2?

Comment: Could you please elaborate and use an answer? @saulspatz